# How to access a public static ArrayList from various classes?

Tags: java, static, arraylist, public

Suppose I have a class

```
    public class c1 {
        public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        public c1() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   //The size of the ArrayList is now 5
                list.add("a");
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I access the same ArrayList in another class, I will get a list with SIZE = 0.

```
     public class c2 {
         public c2() {
             System.out.println("c1.list.size() = " + c1.list.size()); //Prints 0
         }
     }
```

Why is this happening. If the variable is static, then why is a new list being generated for class c2? How can I make sure that I get the same ArrayList if I access it in a different class?

/*************Revised code*****************/

```
     public class c1 {
        public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static void AddToList(String str) {       //This method is called to populate the list 
           list.add(str);
        }
    }
```

But if I access the same ArrayList in another class, I will get a list with SIZE = 0, irrespective of how many times I called AddToList method.

```
     public class c2 {
         public c2() {
             System.out.println("c1.list.size() = " + c1.list.size()); //Prints 0
         }
     }
```

How can I make sure that same changes appear when I use the ArrayList in another class?

Comment: Use Static initialiser block to initialise c1

Answer (score 7):

In your code as is, you should call the `c1` constructor in order to fill the `ArrayList`. So you would need:

```
public c2() {
    new c1();
    System.out.println("c1.list.size() = " + c1.list.size()); //Prints 0
}
```

But this is not good. The best approach would be static initialization by using a `static` block code in `c1` class:

```
public class c1 {
    public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   //The size of the ArrayList is now 5
            list.add("a");
        }
    }

    public c1() {

    }
}
```

As a recommendation from [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197), it would be better to declare the variable as `List<String>` and create the instance as `ArrayList`:

```
public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Another recommendation, use a `static` method to access to this variable instead of making it public:

```
private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public static List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. But if I want to fill my ArrayList in class c1 through a method, then how can I make sure that same changes appear when I use the ArrayList in another class?

Comment: @VijendraSinghAswal you can do it in a `static` method as well, and you must be sure that this `static` method should be called before using the `list`.

Comment: could you please give an example of calling this in a static method.I tried but it works only if I put in a static block.

Comment: @sathishvisa I don't understand your request, which problems do you have?

Comment: @sathishvisa if you're declaring your `List<Whatever>` as `static`, then you should initialize it in a static block.

Comment: I have a static method that populates this `public static List<Whatever>` dynamically.I am trying to access that in another class, but I always get empty array.

Comment: @sathishvisa only after reading [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20482603/1065197) I really understood your problem...