# Static ArrayList accessed from another class is always empty

Tags: java, arraylist, static, static-methods, static-members

I have the following classes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestStaticArrayList {

    public static List<String> numberList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static List<String> getArrayValues(){
    return numberList;
    }

    public static void populateArray() {
    numberList.add("1");
    numberList.add("2");
    numberList.add("3");        
    }
}
```

The static ArrayList in the above class is populated dynamically from a call from below class.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestStaticInvokationClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class staticKlass = Class
        .forName("com.sathish.test.TestStaticArrayList");
    staticKlass.getMethod("populateArray", null).invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the Static ArrayList in the below class.But its always empty.

```
public class StaticArrayListAccessTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    System.out.println(TestStaticArrayList.getArrayValues());

    }
}
```

If I use a

```
static {
...
}
```

to populate the Arraylist it works fine. I have an use case where the ArrayList is populated dynamically which means I cannot use a static {..} block.How can I access the Static ArrayList in this scenario.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Wait, are you running the program two different times? You have two different `main` methods.

Comment: yes.First I run the program to populate the arraylist.Then I tried to access it.

Comment: Static initialization blocks are run automatically upon class initialization. That's why if you use `static {}` your array is already populated.

Comment: It would also help if you told us what exactly you are trying to achieve. Or maybe you're just looking for why that behaviour is occurring?

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most. Remember that votes are not always an accurate reflection of whether you as the asker should accept an answer, but they do help in determining this in concert with knowing that a given answer has helped you.

Comment: Yes,I was curious on why it works with static block and not static methods.

Comment: @sathishvisa You should make it clear from the question what exactly you are trying to find out.

Answer (score 5):

A static field does *not* retain its value across program executions, but only within one execution. The purpose of a static field is to make a value available without having to acquire an instance of any class. Only one main method will be called implicitly so either the list will be populated and forgotten, or the empty list will be read from the other entry point.

The reason `static { }` blocks work is that they get run sometime before the list is retrieved, *no matter the entry point*.

The following will work for this reason:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestStaticInvokationClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class staticKlass = Class
        .forName("com.sathish.test.TestStaticArrayList");
    staticKlass.getMethod("populateArray", null).invoke(null, null);
    System.out.println(TestStaticArrayList.getArrayValues());
    }
}
```

It will populate the ArrayList and then try to read it in the same execution.

**Anyway**, you need not use reflection, as it's slower, riskier, and unwarranted in this situation. Simply do as follows:

```
TestStaticArrayList.populateArray();
```

Comment: so in my case when I have a static block and as soon as I call `TestStaticArrayList.<Somemethod>` anything under that static block will be executed ??

Answer (score 1):

It will be empty, of course. The method `populateArray()` is never called. If you need to see the populated list, you need to do this:

```
TestStaticArrayList.populateArray();
TestStaticArrayList.getArrayValues();
```

FYI, I strongly suggest you change your code structure. There is a reason *static* and *dynamic* are two very different concepts!

Comment: Hint: no need to create an instance of `TestStaticArrayList` since you will only call `static` methods.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Thanks for pointing out the needlessly included line.

Answer (score 1):

From comments: "Yes,I was curious on why it works with static block and not static methods"

Static initialization blocks are **called automatically** when a class is initialized. When is `TestStaticArrayList` initialized? Right here, when you access one of its static methods/fields for the first time ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) is more about initialization ):

```
System.out.println(TestStaticArrayList.getArrayValues());
```

The static initialization block will have already run when you print the results. However, if you don't have any static initialization blocks, then there's no place in the code were the `ArrayList` is populated. That's why in your second program the `ArrayList` is empty. You either populate it in a static initialization block, which is ran automatically, or you call `populateArray()` explicitly before printing its values.

Answer (score 0):

A class isn't just "executed" because it has a `main` method. Such a method is a point of entry to start your program. You will have to invoke the corresponding methods explicitly if that's not your point of entry.

When you call `TestStaticArrayList.getArrayValues()` it will not execute the `main` method in there.

If you execute the program twice it will not know about the values that were in the list the last time: each work separate from eachother.